# Internal compiler error in C++/CLI Code

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli

I translated following C# code

```
using (var a = new A(args1...))
{
    using (var b = new A(args2...))
    {
        dostuff(a,b);
    }
}
```

into C++/CLI Code like this:

```
try
{
    a = gcnew A(args1...);
    b = gcnew A(args2...);

    dostuff(a, b);
}
finally
{
    if (a != nullptr)
        delete a;
    if (b != nullptr)
        delete b;
}
```

Types A, B, dostuff() are part of a .NET library. I dont have the source code of that library.

The library received an update, a constructor got an additional argument.

Now it got messy. I added the additional argument (a `string^`) to both calls (C++/CLI and C#).

Now C# runs just fine, C++/CLI gives an internal compiler error.

> fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
>   (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\cpimport.cpp',
>   line 16424)

VS2017 latest updates

@Some programmer dude: Yes, but atm of the implementation i wasn't certain it is the case in CLI too. Now i know.

@Hans passant: The code worked previously, so i'm pretty sure thats not the case here. I could minimize the example further.

Actually A and B are actually not different types.
'A' has a constructor of the form (c#):

```
A(System.IO.Stream stream); // old version
A(System.IO.Stream stream, string filename); // new version
```

Now the following single line leads to the internal error (c++):

```
A^ a = gcnew A( System::IO::File::Open(filename, System::IO::FileMode::Create), filename);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `delete` accepts null pointers, it simply does nothing then.

Comment: You have stumbled on a bug in your compiler, the best approach is to file it to your compiler vendor and try to find a workaround.

Comment: It happens, the C++/CLI compiler is not that bullet-proof when its parser gets too confused by syntax errors.  The code snippet is not nearly good enough to point the finger, a missing ^ hat on a variable declaration is a common scourge.  You'll have to show us real code.

Answer (score 2):

The code seams ok, I don't know why you get a compiler error but the code might be written much easier.

Simply use the C++/CLI stack semantics:

```
{ 
  A a{args1...};
  B b{args2...};

  dostuff(%a, %b);
}
```

This implies all IDispose using stuff you need.